# Multiple document drawing app Core Data approach

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a working drawing app that uses a Core Data database to store drawings. It allows the user to creates multiple documents but I'm using only one database with multiple drawing entities.

Now I'm making some big improvements in the app and I'm trying to do things right. I think the way to do this kind of app is using **UIManagedDocument**.

My guess is that I should use one UIManagedDocument for every drawing so they'll be saved as independent documents on disk, but I haven't been able to find any examples of this anywhere.

If that's the correct approach (which I'm not sure), I need to know:

- How do I retrieve a list of all the documents (drawings) created?
- How do I save a preview image of the drawing? Do I save it inside the UIManagedDocument or somewhere else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use this article as starting point:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1842295&seqNum=10

The main idea of UIManagedDocument is that each document has it's own managedObjectContext that is persisted in the document's bundle.

> How do I retrieve a list of all the documents (drawings) created?

To display a list of local drawings you could just display your storage directory contents in a collection view.
When dealing with documents stored in iCloud, Apple suggests to use [NSMetadataQuery](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloud101/SearchingforiCloudDocuments/SearchingforiCloudDocuments.html).

> How do I save a preview image of the drawing? Do I save it inside the
>   UIManagedDocument or somewhere else?

To store additional information (like your doc preview) in the bundle, UIManagedDocument provides  [writeAdditionalContent:toURL:originalContentsURL:error:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIManagedDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIManagedDocument/writeAdditionalContent%3atoURL%3aoriginalContentsURL%3aerror%3a)

Please also keep in mind, that NSDocument/UIDocument are controller classes (and not model classes).

Comment: Thanks, that's great info to start with.